# Does an 8 dimensional compact Riemannian manifold contain an embedded minimal hypersurface?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

It is well know that if $(M^{n+1},g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold and $n \leq 6$ then there exists a smooth, embedded minimal hypersurface $\Sigma^n$ in $M$ (infinitely many such $\Sigma$, even)

For $n \geq 7$, the standard theory produces a minimal hypersurface but with an $(n-7)$-dimensional singular set.

Is it actually known that there is an $8$-dimensional compact manifold for which every $7$ dimensional stationary varifold has a singularity?